# JQuery Function Do something - Pause - Do something else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a function where I could execute some jquery code ...then pause for say... 5 secs and then execute something else..

Something like this:

```
function myFunc() {
    var str1 = 'This is the starting text';
        var str2 = 'This is the ending text';
          $("#label").html(str1);

        //I need a pause here (5000 ms) ---

          $("#label").html(str2);

}
```

How can I get a pause in there?

Comment: javascript is single threaded - do you mean lock the browser for 5 seconds or perform some asynchronous operation after 5 seconds?

Comment: you don't want a pause as that will block the entire page. you want to add a window timeout with a callback to take over where you need to continue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done sequentially using jQuery's [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue) method

#### The jQuery way:

```
$('#label')
    .queue(function (n) {
        ...your code here...
        n(); //dequeue the next item in the queue
    })
    .delay(5000)
    .queue(function (n) {
        ...your second bit of code here...
        n(); //dequeue the next item in the queue
    });
```

Although it's good to understand how to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) as well.

The advantage to `queue` is that it works by default along with the `fx` queue, although you could choose to specify a different queue name.

#### The non-jQuery way:

```
function first() {
    ...your code here...
    setTimeout(second, 5000);
}
function second() {
    ...your second bit of code here...
}
first();
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a timeout to handle your pause

```
function myFunc() {
    var str1 = 'This is the starting text';
        var str2 = 'This is the ending text';
          $("#label").html(str1);
          var plzwait=setTimeout(function(){  $("#label").html(str2);  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to accomplish, but you should probably not try to make it synchronus and pause it, that would freeze the application. Instead i suggest you use a timeout, that execute the code you want after a given amount of time.

```
function myFunc() {
    var str1 = 'This is the starting text';
        var str2 = 'This is the ending text';
          $("#label").html(str1);

          setTimeout(function() { 
             // Do what you want to do after a certain time in here 
             $("#label").html(str2); 
          }, 5000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has [delay(](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)) which accepts milliseconds and works with effects.

This is an example giving a fade in when the text changes to bring attention to it.

```
var str1 = "I am the first string";
var str2 = "This is the second string!";
var label = $("#label")
    label.html(str1).delay(5000).fadeOut("fast",function(){label.html(str2)}).fadeIn("slow");
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6zdhZ/)

Comment: The `.delay()` function is just for the animation queue. It won't work for synchronous methods like `.html()`.

Comment: `delay` relies on the queuing, which `.html()` does not support.

Comment: You must have commented right was I deleted it so I could edit it. lol

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout();`

```
function myFunc() {
    var str1 = 'This is the starting text';
        var str2 = 'This is the ending text';
          $("#label").html(str1);

        //I need a pause here (5000 ms) ---
        setTimeout(function(){
         $("#label").html(str2);
        },5000);


}
```